# How to update values in instance when have a custom .update() to update many-to-many relations in DRF writable nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have three models Player, Team, and Membership, Where Player and Team have many-to-many relationship using Membership as intermediary model.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    rating = models.FloatField(null=True)
    install_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    update_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    rating = models.FloatField(null=True)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(
            Player,
            through='Membership',
            through_fields=('team', 'player'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    install_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    update_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)


class Membership(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team')
    player = models.ForeignKey('Player')
    #date_of_joining = models.DateTimeField()
    install_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    update_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Now I was required to update this membership using django rest framework. I tried update those using [Writable nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) by writing a custom `.update()` of team serializer.

```
@transaction.atomic
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    '''
    Cutomize the update function for the serializer to update the
    related_field values.
    '''

    if 'memberships' in validated_data:
        instance = self._update_membership(instance, validated_data)

        # remove memberships key from validated_data to use update method of
        # base serializer class to update model fields
        validated_data.pop('memberships', None)

    return super(TeamSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)


def _update_membership(self, instance, validated_data):
    '''
    Update membership data for a team.
    '''
    memberships = self.initial_data.get('memberships')
    if isinstance(membership, list) and len(memberships) >= 1:
        # make a set of incoming membership
        incoming_player_ids = set()

        try:
            for member in memberships:
                incoming_player_ids.add(member['id'])
        except:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'id is required field in memberships objects.'
            )

        Membership.objects.filter(
            team_id=instance.id
        ).delete()

        # add merchant member mappings
        Membership.objects.bulk_create(
            [
                Membership(
                    team_id=instance.id,
                    player_id=player
                )
                for player in incoming_player_ids
            ]
        )
        return instance
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'memberships is not a list of objects'
            )
```

Now this works well for updating values in database for membership table. Only problem I am facing is that I am not able to update prefetched instance in memory, which on PATCH request to this API updates values in database but API response is showing outdated data.

Next GET request for the same resource gives updated data. Anyone who have worked with many-to-many relation in django and wrote custom update/create methods for writable nested serializers can help me to understand the possible way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to track down the [issue](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2442) in this case. I was using `.prefetch_related()` on queryset which is causing instance to use prefetched data for many to many relations. I have got two solution which may cause a few more database hits to fetch updated data.

## 1. Not using `.prefetch_related()`

One obvious way is not to use `.prefetch_related()` Which is **not recommended** as it will result into high number of DB hits.

## OR

## 2. Fetching updated model instance after updating many-to-many relations in update method of serializer

```
instance = self.context['view'].get_queryset().get(
    id=instance.id
)
```

Modified `.update()` of `TeamSerializer`

```
@transaction.atomic
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    '''
    Cutomize the update function for the serializer to update the
    related_field values.
    '''

    if 'memberships' in validated_data:
        instance = self._update_membership(instance, validated_data)

        # remove memberships key from validated_data to use update method of
        # base serializer class to update model fields
        validated_data.pop('memberships', None)

        # fetch updated model instance after updating many-to-many relations
        instance = self.context['view'].get_queryset().get(
            id=instance.id
        )
    return super(TeamSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

If someone have better approach I would appreciate if they can add an answer to this question.

Comment: As of Django 1.8 there is a builtin function to [refresh an object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database). You could just use `instance.refresh_from_db()`.

Comment: I tried doing that which doesn't work with prefetch_related.

Comment: Well, my comment was only for your second point considering that first point is already in place. And one more thing: Why are you updating the `memberships` from `initial_data` and not from `validated_data`?? Don't you have to use `memberships = validated_data.get('memberships')` in `update_membership` function?

Comment: I have added **OR** in between given two solutions to differentiate that both are independent. As this issue is faced when we use `prefetch_related()` in the queryset.

I'm using initial_data because i was not able to fetch `id` of nested objects from `validated_data` which i was sending in json. I have added custom validation on `membership` key from `initial_data` explicitly. If you have any inputs on retrieving `id` from `validated_data` i would really appreciate that.

Comment: Moreover, `refresh_from_db` doesn't reload ManyToMany and reverse ManyToOne relations, unfortunately

Comment: I am  encountering a similar error can from here help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66741831/api-response-is-showing-outdated-data-with-put-patch-requests

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to "reload" the players field with `instance.players.all()`, because it the queryset is already evaluated in the `is_valid` method of the serializer.

```
@transaction.atomic
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    '''
    Cutomize the update function for the serializer to update the
    related_field values.
    '''

    if 'memberships' in validated_data:
        instance = self._update_membership(instance, validated_data)

        # remove memberships key from validated_data to use update method of
        # base serializer class to update model fields
        validated_data.pop('memberships', None)
        instance.players.all()

    return super(TeamSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

Comment: instance.players.all() didn't work as I am doing prefetch_related() in queryset. To avoid using prefetched data i added a filter like instance.players.filter(is_active=True) which prints updated memberships in console but instance is still not showing updated data in response like before. @ilse2005

Comment: Maybe this new method helps:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database

Comment: I did try this one while debugging the issue but didn't work for instance. I have made a work around this case. I will add an answer to this question soon.

Comment: This issue was because of prefetched data. https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2442#issuecomment-71006996

Comment: @ilse2005, you must be kidding! 1st of all your instance's queryset will **NEVER** get evaluated in serializer's `is_valid` on `update` operation, because it intends to validate your `request.data`. Secondly, if you want to directly clear prefetched related cached objects and update your `QuerySet` results, you should call `instance.players.get_queryset().all()`